# Mapping Id String from JSON to POJO breaks the String?

Tags: java, json, string, gson, httprequest

I'm currently integrating with an API, and when I send a POST request which creates an "order", I receive a JSON response which looks like:

```
{ "OrderCreateResult": 15764514 }
```

However, when I map this JSON into a POJO which looks like:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateCircleGraphicsOrderResponse {
    private String OrderCreateResult;
}
```

and I map it via gson like this:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        CreateCircleGraphicsOrderResponse orderResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), CreateCircleGraphicsOrderResponse.class);
        response.close();
        return orderResponse;
}
```

However, when I retrieve the string via orderResponse.getOrderCreateResult(), and print the string, it indeed is the string I expect, but sending that returned String as a query param for a GET request sends an invalid request, as `orderResponse.getOrderCreateResult().equals("15764514") == False`

Why would the String be broken when mapping to a POJO, even when it prints the same as copy and pasting the string?

This is the GET Request:

```
public CircleGraphicsGetOrder getOrder(String circleGraphicsOrderId) {
        try {
            this.getOrderUrl = this.getOrderUrl.concat(circleGraphicsOrderId);
            URL url = new URL(this.getOrderUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.connect();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ) );

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 2048 );
            for( String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                sb.append( line );
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            return null;
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And the Error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: https://rest.cgorders.com/api/orders/order?access_token=97484431a4525ed2b294b699a3d2f202&id=15764573
```

FINAL EDIT:

I was able to solve this problem by making sure that the "OrderCreateResult" field was an int, and then casting it to a string in the concatenation phase by calling String.valueOf(orderCreateResult).

Comment: The value in the JSON is a number, not a string.

Comment: Can you show the code where you send the GET request? Also show the error from your request.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Instead of `response.body().string()` I passed `"{ \"OrderCreateResult\": 15764514 }"` and `orderResponse.getOrderCreateResult().equals("15764514")` returns `true`.

Comment: Have you considered using a framework for calling the service. That would make this whole situation go away.

Comment: I find that using proven frameworks for doing common tasks is a lot better than writing the code yourself. Consider using spring-boot, spring-web as demonstrated in this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/ Also, it uses Jackson which I find has fewer quirks than Gson. Your entire code could be done in one line using RestTemplate

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just posted my GET request and the error message above. When I hardcode the String as opposed to passing in getOrderCreateResult(), I get a 200OK

Comment: @JanLarsen Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: I wrote it in an answer. Spring is a very nice way of creating programs in a consistent way and their tutorials are great. And what you want to do is trivial with their tools. I realize that it will feel like starting over, but you will soon be happy that you did. Just like lombok right :-)

Comment: What is `this.getOrderUrl`? When I pass directly string representing URL from error everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Pshemo this.getOrderUrl=https://rest.cgorders.com/api/orders/order?access_token=97484431a4525ed2b294b699a3d2f202&id=